# Arduino array and if statement

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have a problem. My code for Arduino is:

```
void count (int a){
  if (a == 0) {
    int led_pin [4] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
  }

  else{
    int led_pin [2] = {4, 5, 6, 9};
  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
    digitalWrite(led_pin[i], HIGH);
  }
}
```

and I get output:

> 'led_pin' was not declared in this scope

How to declared array or change values of array?

Comment: Please read [Variable Declaration](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/VariableDeclaration). The use of array don't make sense as well, so read language reference on [array]( https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/array/) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you have bounded the scope of your led_pin variable inside the if and else condition.

Also you are trying to change the whole variable, you should not do that.

Try this out.

```
void count(int a){
    int led_pin[2][4]={{3,4,5,6},{4,5,6,9}};
    if( a !=0)
    {
        a=1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) //I don't know why you used 7 in your code.
    {
        digitalWrite(led_pin[a][i],HIGH);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.